# Wordpress. Un menú diferente en cada pagina

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy haciendo una pagina web en Wordpress.  La idea es que al entrar  en la pagina de inicio y aparezca el menú principal.  Pero cuando se entre a otra pagina aparezca otro menú.

```
<?php 
    if ( is_front_page()){
        //Static homepage
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'navegation' ) );
    } elseif ( is_home()){
    //Blog page
    } else {
        echo "Menu2";
        //everything else
    }
?>
```

Lo que he logrado con este codigo es que cuando entre a las otras pagina imprima `Menu2`,  pero aun no he podido hacer que aparezca el menu 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes tener diferentes posiciones de menú, por ejemplo cuando las añades en tu `functions.php` de la siguiente manera:

```
register_nav_menus( [
  'front' => __( 'Front navigation', 'context' ),
  'home' => __( 'Home navigation', 'context' ),
  'page' => __( 'Page navigation', 'context' ),
] );
```

Una vez que tengas las posiciones y le asignes cada menú en el administrador a cada posición, puedes mostrar cada menú según la página:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
  wp_nav_menu( [ 'theme_location' => 'front' ] );
}
elseif ( is_home() ) {
  wp_nav_menu( [ 'theme_location' => 'home' ] );
}
else {
  wp_nav_menu( [ 'theme_location' => 'page' ] );
}
```